# Can I re-grow roots from a piece of a trunk cut from my green ash tree?

Tags: trees, roots, bonsai

I have a 3 ft stump of a green ash tree that I pulled out of the ground. I cut 3 root stubs with a chain saw. It's coming from a triple trunk that was rotting out. Is there any way I can regrow the roots where I made the cuts? I'm trying to bonsai the tree. How can I get the roots to grow? The root stumps are 3 inches thick. Thank you.

Comment: Be useful to know exactly which plant we're talking about here and why the triple trunks were rotting - had they been cut down before or were they diseased/dead? Photo of root stumps you're speaking of might clarify things a bit too...

Comment: Im trying to bonsai the section of trunk that I cut out. It's a green ash tree. Im going to carve out the dead wood and put lime sulfur on it but if there's no root ,how do I get the roots started

Answer (score 4):

If you're expecting a piece of cut trunk from an ash tree to develop roots, I'm sorry to tell you it's not going to. Now it's been cut, it's in the process of drying out, so effectively, its already dead. Which is probably just as well, because if its an ordinary ash, they have large composite leaves, and are not ideal subjects for bonsai.

You can grow your own bonsai from seed - you just need to think about what plant you want in relation to where you are going to keep it. Indoor bonsai plants are different from those that need to be outdoors for most of the year. Some information in the link below

http://growabonsai.com/